# How to Downgrade From MariaDB 10.2 to 10.1 on a cPanel Server?

Tags: cpanel, mariadb, whm

I've installed MariaDB 10.2 on a cPanel server using this procedure:

https://confluence2.cpanel.net/display/CKB/How+to+Replace+MySQL+with+MariaDB

But now, I want to downgrade to 10.1 since 10.2 isn't handled by cPanel / WHM.

I know it's technically impossible to "downgrade" so I want to uninstall 10.2 and then install 10.1 from WHM. I will restore the database from a SQL dump afterward.

Any way to do this? How do I uninstall 10.2 and get WHM to install 10.1? I want cPanel/WHM to handle the future MariaDB upgrades.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Its is not possible to do it because cpanel does not support downgrade on database

Comment: Please read my post carefully: "I know it's technically impossible to "downgrade" so I want to uninstall 10.2 and then install 10.1 from WHM. I will restore the database from a SQL dump afterward."

Answer (score 0):

It's quite strange you were able to install MariaDB 10.2 since the upgrade procedure from WHM only allows you to install MariaDB 10.x or MariaDB 10.1.x. If that happened then you probably have other CentOS repos added on the WHM server (like rpmforge/epel etc).

Do you experience any issues with the websites hosted on that server because of MariaDB 10.2 or you just want to be complaint with the recommended versions?!

As a downgrade procedure you will have to manually remove the .rpm packages for MariaDB 10.2 then download the MariaDB 10.1 packages and manually install them (you will need the **yum download only plugin** in order to save the .rpm packages without actually installing them).

I don't know the exact names of those packages but I think it would be better to open a support request on cPanel forums and the cPanel staff guys from there could connect to your server and help you with your issue.